# htaccess RewriteCond to let requests for website.com/m/... stay untouched

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

From a phone, if the user tries to access `website.com`, they are redirected to `mobile.website.com`. However, `mobile.website.com` makes AJAX requests to `website.com`, so I make all requests go through `website.com/m/...`. This isn't working:

```
# redirect phones/tablets to mobile site
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !mobile\.website\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/m/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mobile.website.com/$1 [L,R=302]
```

Specifically the line:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/m/ [NC]
```

It should cancel the rewrite rule if the url matches `website.com/m/...`. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code with this:

```
# redirect phones/tablets to mobile site
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera [NC]mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile) [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !mobile\.website\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(?!m/).*$ http://www.mobile.website.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R,NC]
```

Also if this still doesn't work then please post matching lines from your Apache's `access.log` and `error.log`.